# Break "forall" hypothesis with conjunctions up into components?

Tags: coq

I've the following hypotheses:

```
 H : forall m n : nat,
      f 0 n = S n /\ f (S m) 0 = f m 1 /\ f (S m) (S n) = f m (f (S m) n)
```

My goal is to break it up into it components. However, trying `intros m n in H` or `destruct H` doesn't work. How do I proceed?

I would like something like `H0 : f 0 n = S n`, `H1 : f (S m) 0 = f m 1` and `H2 : f (S m) (S n) = f m (f (S m) n)` with `m` and `n` introduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to specialize the hypothesis to be able to destruct it.

If you already know to which variables you want to apply this hypothesis (let's say you have `n` and `m` already introduced in your environment), you could do the following:

```
specialize (H n m).
destruct H as (H0 & H1 & H2).
```

or shorter:

```
destruct (H n m) as (H0 & H1 & H2).
```

(which also keeps the original hypothesis `H`, while the first solution clears it).

Finally, if you don't know yet to what you are going to apply this hypothesis, you can use the [`edestruct`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.edestruct) tactic:

```
edestruct H as (H0 & H1 & H2).
(* And you get:
H0 : f 0 ?n = S ?n
H1 : f (S ?m) 0 = f ?m 1
H2 : f (S ?m) (S ?n) = f ?m (f (S ?m) ?n)
*)
```